# Two Dimensional int array prints row of values rather than just one

Tags: java, arrays, command-line, int, backtracking

So I have a two-dimensional int array of a given size. I want to assign a value of one to a particular place in this array. I am using the output value from another array. something like this:

```
 public void printQueens(){
   int k = queens[0];
   board[1][queens[0]] = 1;
   System.out.print(queens[1]);}
```

The k value is there to make sure it's an integer value. The queen's array is a one-dimensional integer array of given size. eg. {6,7,2,4}

```
queens = new int[NUM_QUEEN];
```

It is created in a bactracking method:

```
public void backtrack(int row){

    for(int i = 0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++){
        if(canPlace(row,i)){
            queens[row] = i;
            if(row == NUM_QUEEN-1){
                printQueens();               
            }
            else{
                backtrack(row+1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The output I am expecting is a one in the 1st row and queens[0] column (in this case, 7). The output is a row of ones in this 1st row:

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If I place say, 7, in instead of queens[0] output is correct:

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So my question is why is this happening? If a regular explicit integer works, why does an implicit integer not?

Comment: `board[1][k] = 1;` can't possibly update an entire row. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Not too sure exactly how else I could verify. Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: No, please no. Just include the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. See the link above for more information.

Comment: I just edited to try and explain further where queens come from. Hopefully, this helps, I understand it looks very vague. Thanks for the advice

Comment: "The k value is there to make sure it's an integer value." What other kind of value could "it" be? What is the antecedent of "it"?

Comment: I put it there to verify that it is actually an integer I am passing through. It's supposed to be an int I just put it there for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... I've tried to understand your problem. This is a suggestion of code that do what you want (if I understood the problem).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int boardSize = 8;
    int queens[]  = {6, 7, 2, 4};

    int board[][] =   {{0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    int k = queens[0];
    board[1][k] = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
            System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've literally tried out your exact code and got a row of ones. There is clearly something Im missing! I figured someone might know of a certain "glitch" regarding this particular code. Thanks though!

Comment: What is your environment (OS, IDE, JDK)?

Answer (score 0):

The queen's array was never being reset. So when I used the queen array it was just overlaying each value on top of each other because of recursion.